# Get image from public folder NextJS

Tags: next.js, next-images

I'm saving images dynamically. Images stores in public folder of NextJS project.

Path to get image is `/public/upload/catalog/{imagename}`

[image]

As said in NextJS documentation about access to public folder, I'm trying to get this image by path `/upload/catalog/{imagename}`

And it's perfectly works in `development` env, but in `production` I can't access the image.

Example from code of Image component:

```js
<Image
    src={src} //src === "/upload/catalog/1644916867663.jpg"
    width={width || '50'}
    height={height || '50'}
    objectFit={objectFit || 'cover'}
    alt='image'
/>
```

Comment: What does this link return on production?  `"https://{YOUR_DOMAIN}/upload/catalog/1644916867663.jpg"`

Comment: 404. This page could not be found.

Comment: Have you tried to log the `src` in production to see what it output is?

Comment: Are you able to access any of the public files in production? How do you make sure you upload those images under next.js directory? How you checked production file system and checked whether the uploaded files are present or not?

Comment: When I added image to public and build the project, the image appeared on the page.
So then I tried to delete image from public directory, but image anyway apperared on the page.
I think NextJS cached public directory after build
And I cant access to dynamic files with public directory

Answer (score 3):

A bit late maybe, but I faced the same problem and after reading Next.js docs carefully it is crystal clear:

> Note: Only assets that are in the public directory at build time will
> be served by Next.js. Files added at runtime won't be available. We
> recommend using a third party service like AWS S3 for persistent file
> storage.

Therefore using s3 may be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats because in production your base path to the folder /upload is different than your base path in development.